# Two principles involving meets and joins

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, inclusion-exclusion, least-common-multiple

The well-known inclusion-exclusion principle states that for two finite sets $A$ and $B$,
$$|A| + |B| = |A \cap B| + |A \cup B|$$

It is also a simple result that given positive natural numbers $a$ and $b$,
$$ab = \gcd(a, b) \cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$$

I was struck by the similarity between these two formulae, especially considering that $\cap$ and $\cup$ are the meet and join operations in the poset of sets ordered by inclusion, while $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ are the meet and join operations in the poset of numbers ordered by divisibility.  Is there some general principle at work here?

Comment: Residuated lattices might have something to with this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_lattice

Comment: There is also $x + y = \min(x,y) + \max(x,y)$

Comment: @steven if we look at numbers as multisets over the domain {1}, then IEP applies again

Comment: @IstvanChung - there is also a connection to finite deminsional convolution algebras.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this counts as a general principle, but we can view the gcd--lcm result as an application of the IEP if we think of $a$ and $b$ as multisets of the factors in their respective prime decompositions. When conceived of in this way, the the union of these multisets *is* the lcm and the intersection *is* the gcd.

For instance,

$$24 \to \{2,2,2, 3\} =: A$$
$$30 \to \{2,3,5\}=: B$$
$$\mathrm{lcm}(24,30) =120 \approx A\cup B = \{2,2,2,3,5\}$$
$$\mathrm{gcd}(24,30) = 6 \approx A \cap B = \{ 2,3 \}$$

Perhaps these multisets provide the elements to which we might apply the information in @Reveillark's comment.